Python code for extracting rastervalues at point locations
I want to write a python program for extracting rastervalues at point locations. The inputs are a CSV file with point locations having lat & long data and a raster(.tif) file. The raster is in EPSG:4326 projection. I want to transform the points in the same projection first and then extract the values. I am a beginner in this field and don't know how to do it. Would be really helpful if anyone in this community can write a code which does the same job

epsg:4326 is lon/lat (usually)

Does this answer your question? Python - Extract raster values at point locations

Pyproj is a FOSS Python library for the transfomation of vertical coordinate systems.
Rasterio is a FOSS Python library that includes a sample funtion for extracting raster values at X, Y locations.  You will have to study up on reading CSV files and parsing those text lines to get the values from you CSV.
